# Delegate in UISplitView not being called

Tags: ios, delegates, ios5, uisplitviewcontroller

I've set up a delegate methos to communicate from my `masterViewController` to my `detailViewController` but the delegate method isn't getting called.

MasterViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class DetailViewController;
@class MasterViewController;

@protocol MasterViewControllerDelegate
- (void)SelectionChanged:(NSString *)url;
@end

@interface MasterViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<MasterViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@property (strong, nonatomic) DetailViewController *detailViewController;

@end
```

Then in my MasterViewController.m I'm synthesizing the delegate:

```
@synthesize delegate;
```

And finally I'm calling the delegate method from my didSelectRowAtIndexPath method like so:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSArray *links = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                      @"http://www.link1.com",
                      @"http://www.link2.com",
                      @"http://www.link3.com",
                      nil];

   [self.delegate SelectionChanged:[links objectAtIndex: indexPath.row]];
}
```

Then in my DetailViewController.h I have:

```
@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController <UISplitViewControllerDelegate, MasterViewControllerDelegate>
```

And in DetailViewController.m:

```
- (void)SelectionChanged:(NSString *)url {
    NSLog(@"URL is %@", url);
}
```

When I run the app, the `NSLog` from `SelectionChanged` is never called and I get no errors. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure `self.delegate` is not nil?

Comment: I just tested it and sure enough, self.delegate is (null). I guess I should see why that is...

Comment: Can't seem to figure out my delegate is null.... ugh.

Comment: how do you set your delegate?

Comment: Well I figured it out by adding this code to my didSelectRowAtIndex method before my delegate call: DetailViewController *controller = [[DetailViewController alloc] init]; self.delegate = controller; but that doesn't seem right.... allocing my DetailViewCOntroller everytime I select an indexPath??

Comment: I just tried setting it in my appDelegate.m file like so:  NSArray *controllers = splitViewController.viewControllers;
    MasterViewController *rootViewController = [controllers objectAtIndex:0];
    DetailViewController *detailViewController = [controllers objectAtIndex:1];
    
    rootViewController.delegate = detailViewController; but no dice...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand very well the relation between `MasterViewController` and `DetailViewController`: in general the master is the delegate of the detail, but in your code it seems to be the opposite... However, if you don't want to have a different delegate every time you select a row you should assign your delegate somewhere else, like in the initialization of your `MasterViewController`, otherwise it's ok to alloc every time a new one, as long as you remember to (auto)release it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I figured it out... In my AppDelegate.m file I added the following to didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
DetailViewController *detail = (DetailViewController *)navigationController.topViewController;
UINavigationController *masterNavigationController = [splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
MasterViewController *master = (MasterViewController *)masterNavigationController.topViewController;

NSLog(@"%@",masterNavigationController.topViewController);
master.delegate = detail;
```

So the whole method looks like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];
    splitViewController.delegate = (id)navigationController.topViewController;

    DetailViewController *detail = (DetailViewController *)navigationController.topViewController;
    UINavigationController *masterNavigationController = [splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    MasterViewController *master = (MasterViewController *)masterNavigationController.topViewController;

    NSLog(@"%@",masterNavigationController.topViewController);
    master.delegate = detail;

    return YES;
}
```

Basically the problem is that I wasn't assigning the delegate anywhere.... duh.